# Flutter: generate a list in 1 line

Tags: flutter, list

I know how to create a list from others list / map / ... in a simple way.
But I want to do it more quickly because I think it's possible to do it in 1 line.

Example of a list generation from a list of map:

```
List<String> getUserEmailList() {
  List<String> userEmailList = [];
  for (Map<String, dynamic> userDict in globalUserDictList!) {
    userEmailList.add(userDict["email"]);
  }
  return userEmailList;
}
```

How to generate the `userEmailList` from my `globalUserDictList` in 1 line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
List<String> userEmailList = globalUserDictList!.map((e) => e["email"]).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final userEmailList = [for (final (e in globalUserDictList) e["email"] ];
```